# Python in R with reticulate - Numpy [NOT FOUND]

Tags: r, numpy, reticulate

I am trying to use the `reticulate` package in R, which allows Python code within the R environment. Unfortunately I ran into the following problem: even though I have installed the `Numpy` package from Python, R tells me that it is [NOT FOUND], which can be seen in the following output

```
library(reticulate)
py_config()
### Output
python:         C:/Users/X/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/X/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python311.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/X/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311
version:        3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
torch:          [NOT FOUND]
```

I then tried installing `Numpy` again, which resulted in the following:

```
py_install("numpy")
### Output
Using virtual environment "~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate" ...
+ "C:/Users/X/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade --no-user numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\X\docume~1\virtua~1\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (1.25.2)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The solution to my problem was apparently pretty simple. I listed my virtual environments with virtualenv_list(), restarted R and then told R to use the appropriate environment with use_virtualenv().